# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick access Variables Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I am working on app
and there are button, when i clicked on, it will display latitude and longitude for (current location and marker that selected)
for selected marker i create Custom Info Window Adapter 
in this class there are latitude and longitude for selected marker so in `CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java` i have created `GET` method for (latitude and longitude )
and in `MainActivityMaps.java` i created method for button and inside this method i created (two methods for display current and marker selected)
current work well but i have problem (Error) at (marker selected) app crash

**MainActivity.java**

```
// button onclick call  to show latitude and  longitude as a toast for test 
public  void showcurrentlocationattost(View view){
   displaytestcurrent(mLastLocation);
   displayplace(mCurrLocationMarker); // mCurrLocationMarker -> just name 
}

public void displaytestcurrent(Location location){
    LatLng latLngcurrent = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    String text = (String.valueOf("latitude = "+latLngcurrent.latitude+" , "+"longitude = "+ latLngcurrent.longitude));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void displayplace(Marker marker){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CustomInfoWindowAdapter op = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(context); // access getlati for latitude and getlongi //for longitude  From this class  //CutomInfoWindowAdapter.java 
    String text = (String.valueOf("latitude = "+op.getlati()+" , "+"longitude = "+ op.getlongi()));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // for test 
    Log.d("testL", String.valueOf(op.getlati()));
}
```

**CutomInfoWindowAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.mostafa.parking;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter{

    private Marker marker;
    private final View mWindow;
    private Context mContext;
    double lati=0.0;
    double longi=0.0 ;
    String locat;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mWindow = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,null);
    }

    private double rendomWindowtext(Marker marker, View view){
        LatLng location = marker.getPosition();
        String title = marker.getTitle();

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView tvLocat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.locat);
        lati = location.latitude;
        longi = location.longitude;

        if (!title.equals("")){
            tvTitle.setText(title);
        }
        if (!location.equals("")){
            tvLocat.setText(String.valueOf(lati));
        }

        Log.d("lati", String.valueOf(lati));
        Log.d("longi", String.valueOf(longi));
        locat= String.valueOf(location);
        Log.d("Location", String.valueOf(location.latitude));
        String text = (String.valueOf("latitude = "+lati+" , "+"longitude = "+ longi));
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), text,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return lati;
    }

    public  double getlati(){
        LatLng location = marker.getPosition();
        return location.latitude;
    }

    public  double getlongi(){
        LatLng location = marker.getPosition();
        return location.longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        rendomWindowtext(marker,mWindow);
        return mWindow;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        rendomWindowtext(marker,mWindow);
        return mWindow;
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivityMaps" />

    <--onClick="showcurrentlocationattost -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Direction"
       android:onClick="showcurrentlocationattost"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Errors**

```
Process: com.example.mostafa.parking, PID: 5750
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4700)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22288)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4695)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22288) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.getPosition()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.mostafa.parking.CustomInfoWindowAdapter.getlati(CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java:62)
    at com.example.mostafa.parking.MainActivityMaps.displayplace(MainActivityMaps.java:334)
    at com.example.mostafa.parking.MainActivityMaps.showcurrentlocationattost(MainActivityMaps.java:306)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4695) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22288) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, marker is always null.

```
public  double getlati(){
    LatLng location = marker.getPosition();

    return location.latitude;
}

public  double getlongi(){
    LatLng location = marker.getPosition();

    return location.longitude;
}
```

Maybe I missed something, but I see no place that marker is ever set being set in the adapter. You declare it at the top, but it's never set. Hence always null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the **marker** object in **CustomInfoWindowAdapter** is NULL and that's what's throwing the NullPointerException.

One way to solve it is to add the marker in the constructor of that class, I mean replace this:

```
public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    mWindow = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,null);
}
```

with this:

```
public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context context, Marker marker){
    mContext = context;
    mWindow = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,null);
    this.marker = marker;
}
```

And pass the marker when you create the instance in **displayplace**, like this:

```
CustomInfoWindowAdapter op = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(context, marker);
```

Comment: Same Error  https://www.codepile.net/pile/7n3PRpgQ

Comment: When you call **displayplace(mCurrLocationMarker);** are you sure that **mCurrLocationMarker** is not null?

Comment: Unfortunately it is null    https://www.codepile.net/pile/VKYMQaKA                       From Logcat  (05:04:21.310 16061-16061/com.example.mostafa.parking D/NULL: marker is null)

Comment: Well, that's your problem. You are trying to get coordinates of a marker that does not exist. Check your code wherever you set the value of the marker. Or edit your question and show us

Comment: issue Solved 

I'm forgotten put "static" word
static private Marker marker;

Comment: I'm glad you've solve it!